# How to use tcp flags in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, flags

I have problem with my code.
I write a simple tcp packet sniffer, and i need to show tcp packet flags with this code :

```
import socket
import struct


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
        while True:
               packet = server.recvfrom(65565)
               packet = packet[0]
               print "Packing data: "
               print "\n", packet

               ip_header = packet[0:20]
               ip_unpack = struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)
               print "\n Unpack ip header"
               print ip_unpack

               version_ihl = ip_unpack[0]
               version = version_ihl >> 4
               ihl = version_ihl & 0xF
               print ihl
               ip_ihl = ihl * 4
               print ip_ihl

               def getflags(packet):
                       Flag_URG = {1: "URG-Urgent flag)"}
                       Flag_ACK = {1: "ACK-Acknowledgment flag"}
                       Flag_PSH = {1: "PSH-Push flag"}
                       Flag_RST = {1: "RST-Reset flag"}
                       Flag_SYN = {1: "SYN-Synchronize flag"}
                       Flag_FIN = {1: "FIN-End of data flag"}

                       URG = packet & 0x020
                       URG >>= 5
                       ACK = packet & 0x010
                       ACK >>= 4
                       PSH = packet & 0x008
                       PSH >>= 3
                       RST = packet & 0x004
                       RST >>= 2
                       SYN = packet & 0x002
                       SYN >>= 1
                       FIN = packet & 0x001
                       FIN >>= 0


                       new_line = "\n"

                       Flags = Flag_URG[URG] + new_line + Flag_ACK[ACK] + new_line + Flag_PSH[PSH] + new_line + Flag_RST[RST] + new_line + Flag_SYN[SYN] + new_line + Flag_FIN[FIN]
                       return Flags


             #tcp
             tcp_header = packet[ip_ihl:ip_ihl+20]
             tcp_unpack = struct.unpack("!HHLLBBHHH", tcp_header)
             print "\nUnpack TCP header: "
             print "\n", tcp_unpack

             tcp_length = tcp_unpack[4] >> 4

             print "source port: ", tcp_unpack[0]
             print "destination port: ", tcp_unpack[1]
             print "sequence number: ", tcp_unpack[2]
             print "ack number: ", tcp_unpack[3]
             print "dataoffset: ", tcp_unpack[4]
             print "tcp length: ", tcp_length
             print "flag: ", getflags(tcp_unpack[3])

             header_size = ip_ihl + tcp_length * 4
             data_size = len(packet) - header_size
             data = packet[header_size:]
             print "data:"
             print "\n", data
```

but i have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tcp.py", line 67, in <module>
print "flag: ", getflags(tcp_unpack[3])
File "tcp.py", line 49, in getflags
Flags = Flag_URG[URG] + new_line + Flag_ACK[ACK] + new_line +  Flag_PSH[PSH] + new_line + Flag_RST[RST] + new_line + Flag_SYN[SYN] + new_line + Flag_FIN[FIN]
KeyError: 0L
```

how can fix this ? and how can use flags and ecn in tcp packet?

Answer (score 0):

You got KeyError because all the dict objects only have `1` as key. (`Flag_URG`, `Flag_ACK`...) When any flag is missing in `packet`, `0` is used as key so the error occurs.

Add `0` to avoid the Error:

```
                   Flag_URG = {0:"",1: "URG-Urgent flag"}
                   Flag_ACK = {0:"",1: "ACK-Acknowledgment flag"}
                   Flag_PSH = {0:"",1: "PSH-Push flag"}
                   Flag_RST = {0:"",1: "RST-Reset flag"}
                   Flag_SYN = {0:"",1: "SYN-Synchronize flag"}
                   Flag_FIN = {0:"",1: "FIN-End of data flag"}
```

---

It seems `tcp_unpack[3]` is the ack number, so `print "flag: ", getflags(tcp_unpack[3])` looks strange.

Try changing it to `print "flag: ", getflags(tcp_unpack[5])`.